# How to access data from xml response using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I make a cURL request to a website and the response returned is in XML. The request is being done successfully and the resource is created with success. I'm used to accessing data with json but how do I access data/value when the response returned is in XML?

PHP

```
$ch = curl_init($connection_details['api_host_port']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

header('Content-type: application/xml');
print_r($response);
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE OPS_envelope SYSTEM 'ops.dtd'>
<OPS_envelope>
    <header>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </header>
    <body>
        <data_block>
            <dt_assoc>
                <item key="protocol">XCP</item>
                <item key="action">REPLY</item>
                <item key="object">DOMAIN</item>
                <item key="is_success">1</item>
                <item key="response_code">200</item>
                <item key="response_text">
Domain registration successfully completed. WHOIS Privacy successfully enabled. Domain successfully locked.
</item>
                <item key="attributes">
                    <dt_assoc>
                        <item key="admin_email">jsmith@example.com</item>
                        <item key="whois_privacy_state">enabled</item>
                        <item key="registration_text">Domain registration successfully completed. WHOIS Privacy successfully enabled. Domain
successfully locked.</item>
                        <item key="registration_code">200</item>
                        <item key="id">3735281</item>
                        <item key="cancelled_orders">
                            <dt_array>
                                <item key="0">3764860</item>
                                <item key="1">3764861</item>
                            </dt_array>
                        </item>
                    </dt_assoc>
                </item>
            </dt_assoc>
        </data_block>
    </body>
</OPS_envelope>
```

Comment: use ```simplexml_load_string()``` and then ```xpath()```  - https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$ch = curl_init($connection_details['api_host_port']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
header('Content-type: application/xml');
//parse xml string into SimpleXML objects
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r($xml);
```

Example response

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [version] => 0.9
        )

    [body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [data_block] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 200
                                    [1] => Domain registration successfully completed.
Domain successfully locked.
Whois Privacy successfully enabled.
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => DOMAIN
                                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [key] => attributes
                                                )

                                            [dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [item] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Domain registration successfully completed.
Domain successfully locked.
Whois Privacy successfully enabled.
                                                            [1] => 2470645
                                                            [2] => 21834436
                                                            [3] => adams@example.com
                                                            [4] => 200
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => XCP
                                    [6] => REPLY
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```